# Покритикуйте код по задаче со структурами

Tags: c#

Выполнял задачу по структурам. Вроде выполнил правильно, но вышел достаточно кривой код. Прошу дать замечания по коду и проверить правильность выполнения мною задания.

**Задание:**
1. В задаче подразумевается, что исходная информация хранится в текстовом файле input.txt, каждая строка которого содержит полную информацию о некотором объекте, результирующая информация должна быть записана в файл output.txt.
2. Для хранения данных внутри программы организовать массив структур.
3. В типе структура реализуется метод CompareTo интерфейса IComparable, перегружается метод ToString базового класса object и необходимые операции отношения, поля данных и дополнительные методы продумайте самостоятельно.

На основе данных входного файла составить багажную ведомость камеры хранения, включив следующие данные: ФИО пассажира, количество вещей, общий вес вещей. Вывести в новый файл информацию о тех пассажирах, средний вес багажа которых превышает заданный, отсортировав их по количеству вещей, сданных в камеру хранения

**Входной файл:**

```
Anton, 6, 42
Nina, 5, 11
Vasa, 2, 34
Lusa, 3, 48
```

Первое число - это количество вещей, последнее средний вес багажа каждого пассажира.

**Выходной файд:**

```
ФИО Vasa, количество вещей в багаже 2, вес багажа 34
ФИО Lusa, количество вещей в багаже 3, вес багажа 48
ФИО Anton, количество вещей в багаже 6, вес багажа 42

namespace упражнения_2.Интерфейсы
{

    struct BagageList : IComparable
    {
        string Name;
        int CountOfThings;
        public static double Weight;
        double AverageWeight;

        public BagageList(string Name, int CountOfThings, double AverageWeight) : this()
        {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.CountOfThings = CountOfThings;
            this.AverageWeight = AverageWeight;
        }

        public bool checkWeight()
        {
            if (AverageWeight > Weight)
                return true;

            else
                return false;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            BagageList person = (BagageList) obj;
            return this.CountOfThings.CompareTo(person.CountOfThings);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("ФИО {0}, количество вещей в багаже {1}, вес багажа {2}\n", Name, CountOfThings, AverageWeight);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BagageList[] passanger = new BagageList[4];
            string[] fileData =  new string[3];
            string[] fileData2 = new string[4];
            int i = 0;
            int newSize = 0;
            string data = string.Empty;
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\passanger.txt");
            Console.WriteLine("Считывание из файла.");
            while ((data = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string name = string.Empty;
                int things = 0;
                double weight = 0;
                fileData = data.Split(", ".ToCharArray());

                name = fileData[0];
                things = Convert.ToInt32(fileData[2]);
                weight = Convert.ToDouble(fileData[4]);

                passanger[i] = new BagageList(name, things, weight);
                i++;
            }

            foreach (BagageList p in passanger)
            {
                Console.Write(p.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            Array.Sort(passanger);
            BagageList.Weight = 30;

            for (int j = 0; j < fileData2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!passanger[j].checkWeight())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                fileData2[j] = passanger[j].ToString();

                if (!(fileData2[j] == null))
                {
                    newSize++;
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < fileData2.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                string temp;
                if (fileData2[j] == null)
                {
                    temp = fileData2[j + 1];
                    fileData2[j + 1] = fileData2[j];
                    fileData2[j] = temp;
                }
            }

            Array.Resize(ref fileData2, newSize);
            File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\passanger2.txt", fileData2);
            Console.WriteLine("Запись в файл завершенна.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

- использовать кирилицу - ужасная практика
- BagageList - не самое удачное название структуры, не корректно отображает её суть
- если использовали .NET 4.0, можно было бы использовать параметры по умолчанию в конструкторе
- Вместо полей лучше использовать свойства(Properties)
- Метод checkWeight реализовыется так и используеться следующая нотация(не помню её точное название) имени:

  ```
  public bool СheckWeight()
  {
      retrun AverageWeight > Weight
  }
  ```
- и вы не перегрузили операции отношений

Comment: сама задача решена правильно?

Comment: это вашему преподавателю решать

Comment: если задание учебное, это не значит, что преподаватель мне его задал. Может я учусь по учебнику сам и нахожу себе задачи в интернете.

Comment: и правда, не учёл такой ситуации, приношу извинения, а на счёт 

>последнее средний вес багажа каждого пассажира.

по-подробнее: средний вес всех вещей? зачем? почему не общий вес?

Comment: Я предполагал, что это просто вес багажа каждого пассажира. Хотя у меня есть сомнения на счет. не подскажите, что подразумевается в условие. В условие для сохранения в выходной файл нужно сравнивать средний вес багажа каждого отдельно пассажира или средний вес багажа всех пассажиров?

Comment: наверно имеется ввиду несколько иное: записать в выходной файл данные только тех пассажиров, чей ОБЩИЙ вес багажа не превышает велечину заданную вами в программе, но могу ошибаться

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте с двумя копейками. Поле "Средний вес" к чему относится? Если это - полный вес багажа пассажира, деленный на кол-во вещей - то он должен вычисляться, а не быть полем. При этом, вычисляться он должен в структуре Багажный Список. ИМХО.

Comment: Я предполагал, что это просто вес багажа каждого пассажира. Хотя у меня есть сомнения на счет. не подскажите, что подразумевается в условие. В условие для сохранения в выходной файл нужно сравнивать средний вес багажа каждого отдельно пассажира или средний вес багажа всех пассажиров?

Comment: вне зависимости от вариантов, прислушайтесь к совету тов. @BuilderC